# Python framework for time series clustering

Tags: python, scikit-learn

given this dataset:

```
"";"A_001";"A_002";"A_003";"A_004"
"2011-01-01 00:15:00";71,7703349282297;260,416666666667;45,7217504898759;68,203368683718
"2011-01-01 00:30:00";70,7703349282289;270,833333333333;39,1900718484651;68,203368683718
"2011-01-01 00:45:00";62,200956937799;260,416666666667;45,7217504898759;39,6791443850267
"2013-01-06 07:15:00";15,2284263959391;40,5405405405405;1,73761946133797;95,5284552845528
"2013-01-06 08:00:00";13,9593908629442;41,2517780938834;1,73761946133797;119,918699186992
```

Could anyone give me an example of how to plot a time series clustering centroids of the values of the columns  `"A_001";"A_002";"A_003";"A_004"` with the dates on the left by using scikit-learn?

I have already found on google but I have just found how to plot a normal k means clustering, not a time series k mean clustering.

Thank you in advance

Comment: Can you elaborate more on what do you mean by:
> time series k mean clustering

I understand that you want to cluster some data and be sure that time column is taken into account, is that right ?

Comment: In general, only 2D centroids could be plotted. You seem to have 5D centroids. Please explain what you expect to see.

Comment: Hi, thank you all for your replies!! Of course, I put just a part of the entire dataset, because it's too big to share it on Stackoverflow. I need to use the data extracted by the columns to plot  centroids of Time Series Classification and Clustering, like this one: http://nbviewer.jupyter.org/github/alexminnaar/time-series-classification-and-clustering/blob/master/Time%20Series%20Classification%20and%20Clustering.ipynb thank you